# Displaying JSON data only once using either JQUERY or Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi all can anyone help me on how to display JSON data only once so for example
I have displayed the information for Person number 1 and then I hover over the name of Person number 2 and then hovered back to Person number one instead of displaying the information of Person 1 again it will just highlight the already displayed the previously displayed information of Person 1

Here is my code for displaying information

```
foreach (i = 0; i < PersonInfo.length; i++) {
    if (e.target.parentNode.parentNode == PersonInfo[i])
    {
        index = i;
        break;
        //document.getElementById("rightcontainer").style.backgroundColor = "green" ;
    }
}



var html += '';
html += '<div id="infocontainer">';
html += '<div class="p-image"><img src="src/images/someimage.png"/></div>';
html += '<div class="popupdetail">';
html += '<div class="p-name"> Person Name: ' + Person[index].person_name+ '</div>';
html += '<div class="p-name"> Status: ' + Person[index].status + '</div>';
html += '<div class="p-name"> Country: ' + Person[index].country + '</div>';
html += '</div>';
html += '</div>';
```

Any help?

Comment: *"...and then I hover over the name of Person number 2..."* **OK** *"...and then hovered back to Person number one..."* **I'm with you so far** *"...instead of displaying the information of Person 1 again..."* **You want the info of Person 2?** *"... it will just highlight the already displayed ..."* **That would be Person 2** *"...the previously displayed information of Person 1."* **Huh?! ...What?**

Comment: Wouldn't be less confusing if you just said, "I'm trying to display the info for each Person when hovered on? Here's what you just said: . "When hovering over Person 1--Person 1 info popup." 2. Then onto P2 info P2 is up. 3. Then go back to P1 and instead of P1 info again,,, it will just highlight the already ..the previously displayed information of P1. NO sense whatsoever.

Comment: @zer00ne sorry dude im just a newbie to javascript/jquery and sorry im not that good at english :-) anyway my scenario is that I have this div for container then if that container displayed person 1 it will stay there then if I hover at person 2 it will display below the info of person 1 (hope you still got it) then if I hovered back to person 1 instead of displaying it below person 2 it will just highlight the information of person 1 that is displayed above Person 2 :-)

Comment: OK so your info is in one place it doesn't show in it's proper place under its corresponding area.

Comment: @zer00ne no how can I explain it umm it goes like this

Person 1 -> I hovered it first the I hovered over
Person 2 -> OK, then hovered back to Person 1
(expected result would be like this)
Person 1 -> being highlighted and not displaying below Person 2

Answer (score 0):

Your code is incomplete, but I suspect you have more than one element with the same `id` of `infocontainer`?

Anyway, here's how to do this using a single `<div id="infocontainer">`:

```js
var PersonInfo = [{
  person_name: "Alice",
  image_url: "https://placeimg.com/100/50/people",
  status: "alive",
  country: "USA"
}, {
  person_name: "Bob",
  image_url: "https://placeimg.com/100/50/people/sepia",
  status: "deceased",
  country: "Australia"
}];

PersonInfo.forEach((pi, i) => {
  $("#persons div").eq(i).hover(function() {
    $i = $("#infocontainer");
    $i.find(".p-image img").attr("src", pi.image_url);
    $i.find(".p-name span").text(pi.person_name);
    $i.find(".p-status span").text(pi.status);
    $i.find(".p-country span").text(pi.country);
    $i.show();
  }, function() {
    $("#infocontainer").hide();
  });
});
```

```css
#persons div {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 2em;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 1em
}

#infocontainer {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  top: 20px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="persons">
  <div>Alice</div>
  <div>Bob</div>
</div>

<div id="infocontainer">
  <div class="p-image"><img src="" /></div>
  <div class="popupdetail">
    <div class="p-name"> Person Name: <span></span></div>
    <div class="p-status"> Status: <span></span></div>
    <div class="p-country"> Country: <span></span></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: sorry for incomplete codes im just a beginner in this javascript, ill try your sample codes, an update you

Comment: how can I post my screenshot here regarding my result